# How to create vertical line in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using iReport-3.7.4 ,

I want to make table in detail like this ,

[image]

but , the line in this table can't longwise until the end of the table, 
I've placed this table in detail ..

Comment: You should set border

Answer (score 3):

In iReport, Right Click on a Field, and goto Padding and Borders and set Line width to 1. As shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Put the repetitive things in sub-report and draw the vertical lines in appropriate margins. Load the sub-report in the main window with its width tallies with the parent width. Test & modify the report again an again till you get the lines in the correct places. Moreover make sure you have checked on ***Print Repeated Values*** property for the line.

I've attached some reports I've created for my project, hope they can explain you well.

**The Parent Report**
[image: The parent report]

**The Sub-Report**
[image]

**The Final Output**
[image]

Comment: And I'm using iReport 4.7.1

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to draw a line then just drag line element from palette and drag the bottom middle point of that tile element to increase the size and then decrease the width by dragging left middle point.